# Chrome Extension Popup styling breaking in generated frame

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, bootstrap-4

I have a simple table styled with bootstrap I am trying to display in the Popup of a chrome extension. The on-hover styling that should be applied to each row stops working towards the bottom of the list.

I can load up the popup.html in its own window (via `chrome-extension://<my_extension_id>/popup.html` and the styling renders just fine.

Here's a pared down version of what my `popup.html` looks like:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="width:  200px;">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test (hover styling breaks here)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

I would expect there to be no difference between what chrome's popup window renders and what renders when viewing the popup in its own page. I have experienced similar other anomalies trying to build the styling for my popup. I'm hoping that if I can find an answer to this question, I can apply it to the other issues I've seen.

EDIT: here are some .gifs demonstrating the difference in behavior:

[In Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vjq1.gif)

[In Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws8kp.gif)

I should also note that I can use chrome DevTools to manually set the `:hover` property, the table row's styling updates correctly.

Comment: I don't see any difference here. I think you should provide more details as to how exactly you're opening that popup/window in both cases and maybe screenshots of the desired/observed behavior? P.S. make sure your styles don't set `position` on `body` or `html`.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thanks for taking a look at this. I've included a couple of gifs in my question to illustrate what I'm seeing.

I am opening the popup simply by clicking on the extension's icon in the chrome toolbar. In order to view the popup in its own page, I am using devtools to open up the Source tab, then right click on `popup.html` -> Open in New Tab.

Comment: I see the difference in your gifs, but I definitely can't repro it here. Do you see this with the posted html fragment? If so, looks like a bug so consider reporting it on https://crbug.com if it's not already there. Could be OS-specific as well, I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, I can see the issue with the above html fragment. I'll head over to crbug.com and see if I can make any headway there.
You make a good point about the OS, I am using a mac. I'll spin up a windows 10 VM to see if I have any success with that.


EDIT: to follow up, I am _not_ seeing this issue when I load this extension in my Win10 VM. Thanks for the tip @wOxxOm, I can narrow down my search.

Comment: I remember seeing several MacOS-specific reports there about the popup being partly nonfunctional or incorrectly displayed when it's on a second display (or on a Retina display), something like that.

Comment: Oh wow, that's it! I didn't even consider that I have been trying this on my second screen. The styling works just fine if I view the popup on my main screen. I'd like to accept that comment as the answer, but it seems like that's not possible?

Comment: Could be https://crbug.com/659642 which applies to both Windows and MacOS judging by the comments.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. I'm new to contributing to StackOverflow, how should I resolve this ticket?